# Node.js app crashes when creating indexes for mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When i creating indexes via `createIndex` or `ensureIndex` methods my node.js app crashing without providing any details of occured error.

Also i have noticed that all my code works very well with my localhost mongodb until i use remote mongdb atlas replica set.

Node.js: 8.5.0
Mongodb: 3.6.4
Mongodb driver for Node.js: 3.0.8

Example code (but i have tried different variants of implementation, nothing helps):

```
db.collection('stars').ensureIndex({name: 1}, { unique: true });
```

I am already listening for `uncaughtException` and `unhandledRejection` events, but they dont fire on this crash.

What can i do to get details or get rid of this error?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated my mongodb driver to version 3.1.0 and eventually got error message with description of reason that causes the problem. According to error message: "**The field "retryWrites" is not valid for for an index specification**". So, i think the problem was with this field that i used to add to my connection uri string. After removing this field i got rid of this problem.

Comment: Does your app need to create indexes every time it runs or on the fly? Might be better to separate index creation out so you can leave retryWrites enabled.

Comment: Yes, on every starting of app I am using `ensureIndex` method to create indexes if they are not existing yet. Do you think its a bad practise ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be connected with this issue: [NODE-1641](https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/NODE/issues/NODE-1641?filter=allopenissues). I've got similar problem and found a few solutions:

- Locking driver version at 3.1.0 and adding useNewUrlParser: true in connection options.
- In createIndex add field retryWrites: null, so in your case it will look like: 
  `db.collection('stars').ensureIndex({name: 1}, { unique: true, retryWrites: null })`;

However you need to check if it won't turn off retryable writes for that collection.

- Last option is to vote up that issue and hope that it will be resolved soon, and then update your driver.

Comment: They fixed it in 3.1.8

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I'm currently trying to work around this.

If you remove {unique: true} it should get the job done, but it will make duplicate documents if you add the same document over again.